How to perform Quantum Espresso DOS and band structure calculation using HSE06 for 2D materials?
How can I perform DOS and band structure HSE06 calculations for 2D materials using Quantum Espresso? I'm working on $\ce{MoS2}$.
&CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'MoS2'
  pseudo_dir = '/home/sana/pseudo'
/
&SYSTEM
  ecutrho =  120
  ecutwfc =  30
  ibrav = 4
  a=3.184066,
  b=3.184066,
  c=18.127112,
  nat = 3
  nbnd = 30
  input_dft = 'hse'
  exx_fraction = 0.25
  nqx1 = 2
  nqx2 = 2
  nqx3 = 1
  ntyp = 2
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr = 1.0d-6
  mixing_beta =   0.7
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Mo     95.96 Mo.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
S      32.065 S.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Mo           0.0000000000       0.0000000000       0.5000000000 
S            0.3333333333       0.6666666667       0.4217548051
S            0.3333333333       0.6666666667       0.5782450789
K_POINTS automatic
6 6 2 0 0 0


Could you provide your input file for a regular PBE or whatever non-hybrid calculation you are doing? You only need to modify a few keyword in the input files such as input_dft, nqx1, nqx2, nqx3, x_gamma_extrapolation, exxdiv_treatment, ecutfock, etc. If you provide the input files, I can write an answer.

sir kindly share me your e mail address i ll send you my input files

You can copy the content of your input file, and paste it in your post as a code block. Use the Edit button below the post to add your input file

https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/6055/abdul-muhaymin-free-palestine

sir kindly check my question i uplode my scf file

What type of results do you want to obtain? I am a little confused. The input file you uploaded is already for a HSE06 scf calculation. Did you mean calculating DOS or maybe band structure using HSE06?

band structure & DOS both

Did you check those two links given in the previous comment? In those link, it is explained step by step how to perform such calculations using hybrid functionals. If you have specific problem following the instruction, you can ask a new question. The procedure is same for 2D/3D materials.
